# Laravel - Displaying items from Collection and their sum from the related table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, laravel-5

I'm having problems wrapping my brain around this.

I have two tables:

```
Users
+---------+
| id name |
+---------+
| 1 John  |
| 2 Ann   |
| 3 Joe   |
+---------+

Products
+---------------------+
| id product users_id |
+---------------------+
| 1  Bread      1     |
| 2  Apple      1     |
| 3  Egg        2     |
| 4  Juice      3     |
| 5  Cheese     3     |
| 6  Carrot     3     |
+---------------------+
```

I want to make a query that will display a user and the number of articles in the products table which refer to him. Like this:

```
+----------------------+
| name sum_of_products |
+----------------------+
| Ivan       2         |
| Ann        1         |
| Joe        3         |
+----------------------+
```

I have working models and relationships.
I can do a query just for one user like this

```
$sum = User::whereId(1)->products()->count();
```

but how can I select all users and get all their counts in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you need with:

```
$users = User::leftJoin('products', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')->select('user_id', 'user.name')->selectRaw('count(*) as cnt')->groupBy('products.user_id')->get();
```

Then you can access the count and user like that:

```
foreach($users as $user) {
  $username = $user->name;
  $productCount = $user->cnt;
  ...; //do whatever you need with that data
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, i completely forgot about joins.

Answer (score 3):

What about laravels accessor functionality?

Your user model should look something like this:

```
namespace App;

class User extends Model
{

    protected $appends = array('sum_of_products');

    public function getSumOfProductsAttribute() {

        return $this->products()->count();
    }
}
```

check out the [docu](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Answer (score 0):

This is the plain `SQL`

```
SELECT users.name, count( products.users_id ) as sum_of_products
FROM products LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=products.users_id 
GROUP BY products.users_id
```

In laravel try this out and see how it works out:

```
$products = Products::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'products.users_id')
  ->select('users.name', 'count(products.users_id) as sum_of_products')
  ->groupBy('products.users_id')
  ->get();
```